# Facebook API's fb:registration returning "Invalid 'client_id'" when not connected to Facebook

Tags: facebook, fbml, registration, facebook-fbml

I'm trying to use Facebook's registration tool for my website. I would like to allow Facebook users to login seamlessly to my website, but also non-Facebook users to create an account through that unified UI.

I'm using the `<fb:registration>` tag for that purpose. If I'm already connected to Facebook when arriving to the page, everything works as expected (the form is prefilled with information from my Facebook account). But if I'm not connected to Facebook, the following error is displayed: `Invalid 'client_id'.`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much for your help.

You'll find below the HTML code rendered from the server:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'>
<head id='head'>
<title>MyWebSite - Signup</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/client/Core.css'/>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='/client/jQuery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function initialize() {
 $.getScript('client/Core.js');
 $.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId   : 123456789, // replaced here by my App ID
  session : {},
  status  : true,
  cookie  : true,
  xfbml   : true
 });
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
  window.location.href = 'DoLogin';
 });
};
</script>
</head>
<body onload='initialize();'>
<span id='fb-root'></span>
<fb:registration 
    fields='[{"name":"name"},{"name":"first_name"},{"name":"last_name"},{"name":"email"},{"name":"location"},{"name":"gender"},{"name":"password","view":"not_prefilled"},{"name":"captcha"}]' 
    redirect-uri='http://172.16.100.31/DoSignup'
    width='600'
    fb_only='false'
    allowTransparency='true'>
</fb:registration>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might have to configure your application to let users other than the developers to access the app. I had a hard time finding it, but if I remember well, it was a matter of sandboxing the app or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! That makes sense, but the ambiguous error message doesn't really help...

Comment: In your app on the developer page, go to About->Advanced->Authentication->Sandbox Mode and click Disabled.  

I enabled this thinking it'd be fine since I only want developer access, but I guess that's incompatible with registation! Silly me.

Comment: OMG this was killing us - thank you so much! This was a real doh! moment.

Comment: and sandbox was the solution.

Comment: Phew, thanks for that. Facebook and their lack of documentations!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, except I had the sandbox disabled already. 
I had included the script tag as

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={YOUR_APP_ID}&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration 
  fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
  redirect-uri="https://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo/"
  width="530">
</fb:registration>
```

as it was on the [registration example page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/), however, the [JavaScript SDK page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) had

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```

Removing the `#appId={YOUR_APP_ID}&xfbml=1` from the external script tag did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you registered your application with Facebook they will give you an appID which you will need to use instead of the '123456789' AppID in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already own a Facebook app ID, which I'm using instead of the "123456789" above. I was using this fake number just to avoid giving out my app ID.
Other than that, do you see anything wrong in the code above? If you own an app ID, could you copy/paste this code and try it out with your app ID?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here - because I had a similar but non-identical problem:

If you use the Facebook XFBML code on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ and replace the word {YOUR_APP_ID} by {1234123434534} (or whatever), it fails because it isn't expecting the curly brackets. (Different from various other areas that use JSON and **are** expecting them).

I don't know if this is what you've done wrong, but it's an easy mistake to make, as I just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

For testing set your `YOUR_APP_ID` to `113869198637480`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was displaying the fb registration link without logging in the user first. After scratching my head for a long time, I asked the user to log in through facebook before presenting the registration form. The error was gone much to my delight.