# Facebook Registration plugin: "invalid_id" when logging out

Tags: facebook, registration, user-registration

I've just set up a Facebook Registration plugin here http://www.lexpressproperty.com/en/register.

I works like a charm but I encounter the following issue: whenever a user wants to logout (using the "x" next to his profile), he gets the following message:

> Unable to load the registration form for . You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app. (Error: Invalid 'client_id'.)"

If the user then refreshes the page, the form is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is in [sandbox status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845721/facebook-apis-fbregistration-returning-invalid-client-id-when-not-connecte)

I also had the same issue, really frustrating. But it was false alarm. Above solution worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a problem with sandbox, as you can register if you refresh the page after logging out. By the way, the app is not sandboxed.

Comment: May be the fbml control that you use have some issues. Because if the user initially not logged in to Facebook and access your page, then its empty, if we try to logging in from the link listed in that page, then it goes to the same error page. See my answer with sample code that I used.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following, it works fine in all scenarios. Try this out. Note that you need to have a live url for the redirect_uri field in the same app domain specified in the Facebook app config.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=999999999999&redirect_uri=@ConfigCaller.redirectURI&fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email,first_name,last_name"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="390"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, it won't logout with this code: http://www.lexpressproperty.com/en/register/pro?mode=iframe

Comment: How do we solve it when i have to use the <fb:registration> tag .. i need custom fields in the form and i cant really use the iframe method

Comment: I am afraid I have not tried out other approaches. May be you can update it here if you find a solution for these guys.