# Facebook Registration not working "(Error: Invalid 'client_id'.)"

Tags: php, html, facebook, iframe, registration

I'm using the FB registration iFrame code on my site. I've followed all the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ but I can't understand why I have this error. The only thing I've ever been able to see is a red box with the words `"Unable to load the registration form for . You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app. (Error: Invalid 'client_id'.)"` I've looked into what I says about apps being blocked, but this is simply NOT the case. The app is not blocked. I've even tried viewing the page with multiple FB accounts. This error is always displayed. I looked into my app settings to see if anything was wrong there. Some report that "Sandbox Mode" must be disabled or you can get this error, but mine is disabled. Always has been. I tried deleting the whole app all together and starting fresh. After doing so I get the same result.

One thing perhaps worth mentioning, my app is listed as "Unlisted" in the App center. Many are having this issue for unexplained reasons by FB.

> App Detail Page Status: Live Your app detail page is now live and will
>   appear in Search.
>
> App Center Listing Status: Unlisted Your app is not
>   listed because it does not have enough high ratings and user
>   engagement to be listed in the App Center at this time. Please refer
>   to your app's Insights page to view your app's user rating and
>   engagement metrics, and view our App Center guidelines for more
>   information.

Also another thing perhaps worth mentioning, I currently have a login and registration setup on the root of the website. I'm building a whole new site in a subdirectory where I'm trying to place the new FB login and registration. Could this be causing a conflict in some way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with your app’s app center status.

In your document’s code, where the registration form iframe is embedded, it looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?<br />
             client_id=113869198637480&<br />
             redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&<br />
             fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email" <br="">
        scrolling="auto"&lt;br />
        frameborder="no"&lt;br />
        style="border:none"&lt;br />
        allowTransparency="true"&lt;br />
        width="100%"&lt;br />
        height="330">&lt;br />
</iframe>
```

– of course with this code the plugin does not load correctly, because the `src` URL you have given for the iframe address is invalid, and so Facebook does not get the parameters the plugin needs.

Remove the line breaks in it, remove the `<br>` elements that have no business being in the `<iframe>` tag. (I suppose the CMS you might be using for your page might have caused this, if it interpreted the code you input as text that’s got to be formatted.)

Comment: What do you mean the src is invalid? That is the src that is provided in the code on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: Yes, it’s _formatted_ there with line-breaks in the URL, for readability reasons. But of course, in your _actual_ code, there __must be absolutely no__ line breaks and especially no `<br>` tags inside the URL value.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845721/facebook-apis-fbregistration-returning-invalid-client-id-when-not-connecte), it may help you.  you may like to try the solution `Remove the #appId={YOUR_APP_ID}&xfbml=1` from the external script tag. 
hope it helps. btw it is also a [reported bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/257493511023158?browse=search_5087a30b0b0045258312491)

Answer (score -2):

You should Create a facebook App

get the app ID and replace it with the Client_id in the registration page

> client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
>                redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
>                fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email" 
>           scrolling="auto"<br />
>           frameborder="no"<br />
>           style="border:none"<br />
>           allowTransparency="true"<br />
>           width="100%"<br />
>           height="330"><br />